# How to output content based on same custom taxonomy?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, post-type, tax-query

I have been trying to output content of all post-types (Posts, Pages and CPTs) based on a term of a custom taxonomy that they **must** share (meaning if they don't share that particular term, the output should not include that post-type).

Here is what I have so far:

```
$term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'persons', array('fields' => 'names')); // persons is the custom taxonomy
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => array( 'post', 'page', 'profile', 'letter' ), // profile and letter are CPTs
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                'taxonomy' => 'persons',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $term_list
                )
            ),
        'post__not_in'=>array($post->ID)
    );

$related_content = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $related_content->have_posts() ) {
    echo __('Related Content (profiles, pages, articles, letters):', 'teselle');
    echo '<ul class="related-content">';
    while ($related_content->have_posts()) { 
        $related_content->the_post();

        echo '<li><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';

    } // endwhile
    echo '</ul>';
} // endif

wp_reset_query(); wp_reset_postdata();
```

The problem with the above code is that it outputs too much.

If I fill in the exact slug of the term I need, for example `'terms' => 'the-exact-slug'`, it works perfect, but I really need it to be a variable.

Can someone point out what my mistake is in the above code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we meet here again :)

Try using this:

```
$term_list = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'persons', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
```

and

```
'tax_query' => array(
     array(
         'taxonomy' => 'persons',
         'field' => 'id',
         'terms' => $term_list
         )
     ),
```

AFAIK, the `tax_query` accepts field by `id` or `slug` only (see [here](http://look4wp.com/WP_Query%5d). And the `wp_get_post_terms` accepts only `names` (not slug), `ids` and `all`. So the match between them is only `id`.

**Update**

If you need `slug`, use this:

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'persons' );
$term_slugs = wp_list_pluck( $terms, 'slug' );
```

Comment: thanks for your input @Rilwis. This outputs the correct IDs, but how to get the slug (that I really need) from those IDs?

Comment: Updated the answer with code to get term slugs.

Comment: that works indeed, in the tax_query I changed the `'field'` back to `'slug'`
thanks so much! On to the next challenge as this only outputs the related profile CPT, not other content :)

Answer (score 0):

You might try the slugs instead of the names, i.e.

```
$term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'persons', array('fields' => 'slug'));
```

instead of

```
$term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'persons', array('fields' => 'names'));
```

since your are using

```
'field' => 'slug',
```

in the tax query.

**EDIT:**

```
$term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'persons', array('fields' => 'ids')); // persons is the custom taxonomy
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'=>-1,
        'post_type' => array( 'post', 'page', 'profile', 'letter' ), // profile and letter are CPTs
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                'taxonomy' => 'persons',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $term_list
                )
            ),
        'post__not_in'=>array($post->ID)
    );
```

I added posts_per_page to return all results and use ids in the wp_get_post_terms and id in the tax_query.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that is not it. If I change it to `slug` the thing falls apart, if I change it to `slugs`nothing changes.

Comment: ok, I updated the code above, let's see what happens ;-)

Comment: still outputs content that is not linked in any way...

Comment: strange, it seems to work on my install (tested only with one cpt)

Comment: maybe you can debug it with **print_r($term_list);** and then try for example some handpicked array on **'terms' => array(123,321)** using the relevant ids.

Comment: well, that is what I already said in the beginning, if I fill in the exact slug for terms (as in: `'terms' => 'the-exact-slug'`) AND using my original code, it works perfectly. The entire problem is how to get that slug dynamically.

Comment: You use array('fields' => 'names') so this could be like "John Smith" but then you use 'field' => 'slug' in the tax_query, and that is looking for inputs like "john-smith" o array("john-smith","james-bond"). That was my idea where the problem might be, and so using ids instead might be a way to get rid of this problem ;-)

Comment: ok, fair enough :) but as I need the slug, I still should find a way to get that slug from the ID, right?